# nice overload structure

Tags: asp.net

I have created a library function and want to add an overload that does a very similar thing with an additional parameter. The existing code looks like this:

```
public class MealsAllocation
{
    public int mealId;
    public List<CrewSummary> crew;

    private MealsAllocation() { }
    public MealsAllocation(int MealId) {
        mealId = MealId;
        string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalSqlServer"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);

        //first fill an ienumerable redemption object for the meal
        List<MealRedemption> mealRedemptions = new List<MealRedemption>();
        SqlCommand cmdRed = new SqlCommand("tegsGetMealsRedemption", conn);
        cmdRed.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmdRed.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@mealId", MealId));
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader drRed = cmdRed.ExecuteReader();
        while (drRed.Read())
        {
            MealRedemption mr = new MealRedemption(Convert.ToInt32(drRed["crewId"]), Convert.ToDateTime(drRed["creation"]), Convert.ToInt32(drRed["redeemed"]));
            mealRedemptions.Add(mr);
        }
        conn.Close();

        //then fill the crew list
        crew = new List<CrewSummary>();
        SqlCommand cmdCrew = new SqlCommand("tegsGetMealsAllocation", conn);
        cmdCrew.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmdCrew.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@mealId", MealId));
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader drCrew = cmdCrew.ExecuteReader();
        while (drCrew.Read())
        {
            int drCid = Convert.ToInt32(drCrew["id"]);
            List<MealRedemption> drMr = mealRedemptions.FindAll(red => red.crewId == drCid) ;
            CrewSummary cs = new CrewSummary(drCid, Convert.ToInt32(drCrew["allocation"]), drMr );
            crew.Add(cs);
        }
        conn.Close();

    }
```

So then now I wish to add a new overload that will look a bit like this:

```
    public MealsAllocation(int MealId, int crewId)
    {
    }
```

and essentially this will do much the same but slightly different from the above.

What would be a good strategy to avoid "copy and paste inheritance" ?
ie a nice way to refactor the above so that it lends itself more easily to the overload?

Comment: what an amazingly useful set of answers, I've learn't something from all of them - thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about moving your logic to an `internal` function so it's only accessible in this assembly, and to this class and use [optional parameters](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/02/optional-parameters-and-named-arguments-in-c-4-and-a-cool-scenario-w-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx)... something like this:

```
public class MealsAllocation
{
    public int mealId;
    public List<CrewSummary> crew;

    private MealsAllocation() 
    {
    }

    public MealsAllocation(int MealId) 
    {
        DoWork(MealId);
    }

    public MealsAllocation(int MealId, int crewId)
    {
        DoWork(MealId, crewId);
    }

    internal void DoWork(int MealId, int crewId = -1)
    {
        // have your logic here based on your parameter list

        // valid crewId passed, then add new param for DB proc
        if (crewId > -1)
        {
            cmdCrew.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@crewId", crewId));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Reason for downvote?  Although I haven't tested this code, I think it's a valid solution...

Comment: the biggest problem i had with thinking this through was I really wasn't sure where to put the new intermediate logic, internal is very useful to me - i like this a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

You can user object initializer

```
var mealRedemption = new
{ 
  MealId = yourvlue,
  Crew = crew
};
```

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that comes to mind is to split that big chunk of code in two different methods
giving at each method a specialized functionality

```
public MealsAllocation(int MealId) 
{
    List<MealRedemption> mealRedemptions = LoadMealRedemptions(MealID);
    LoadCrewSummaryByMeal(mealRedemptions, MealID);
}
```

while the other constructor could be

```
public MealsAllocation(int MealId, int crewId) 
{ 
    List<MealRedemption> mealRedemptions = LoadMealRedemptions(MealID);
    LoadCrewSummaryByCrew(mealRedemptions, MealID, crewID);
}
```

In the first constructor you call the private method where you load the MealRedemptions list, get its output and pass to a specialized method that load the CrewSummary list using only the MealID and the list obtained from the first method.

In the second constructor you could use the same method used in the first one and then use a different one for the loading of the CrewSummary. The requirements of your second constructor are not clear and could change the design of this second method (I mean, how do you use the crewID parameter to change the inner workings to build the CrewSummary list?)

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to overload your **constructor**, you could also try such an approach:

```
public MealsAllocation(int MealId) : this (MealId, null)
{
}
public MealsAllocation(int MealId, int? crewId) 
{
  // Initialize your instance as needed
  if (crewId.HasValue)
  {
    // Do some more stuff
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't recommend doing all that inside the constructor, you can simply add an optional param to the end:

```
public class MealsAllocation  
{  
    public int MealId { get; set; }
    public int CrewId { get; set; }

    public List<CrewSummary> Crew { get; set; };

    public MealsAllocation(int mealId, int crewId = 0)  
    {  
        this.MealId = mealId;
        this.CrewId = crewId;

        if(this.CrewId = 0) // etc...
}
```

Side note: You need to add the `using` statement around your `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` object or you could run into connection and/or memory leaks.  Personally, I'd create a Data Access layer and put all of the data related methods there to make them reusable across your entire business layer.

Also, I think this might be a good candidate for the `Lazy<T>` object: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx